# Please suggest the Intermediate file format at conversion of PDF DOC RTF HTML

Tags: file, formats

I'm going to write some converters.

I fought HTML is the best for that. For example:
- at first, i create HTML->PDF
- at second, i create DOC -> HTML (and get DOC->PDF also)
...so i will have 3 converters instead of 2.

What intermediate format can you suggest? (is the XML better for my task, but how to preserve formatting styles)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HTML as an intermediate language has it's limitations - you need to supplement it with CSS to capture presentational aspects. Separation of content and presentation is useful though.

Have you considered using a [plain text](https://superuser.com/questions/209897/text-formatter-tools/209902#209902) format such as [multimarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) or [textile](http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/)?

Otherwise I would suspect that something like [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) or [RTF](http://www.snake.net/software/RTF/) would allow you to capture more of the presentation layout.

There already exist many applications that do what you describe. For example [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

Answer (score 0):

I think XML is the best intermediate format for any conversion. Also, you may use your own text or binary format.

Comment: Well, how do i save table borders(or other formatting) in XML?

Comment: use your imagination: you can hold left, right, top and bottom padding =)